# Best practice when setting a string to (possibly) its own value?

Tags: c++, qt

Community,

I have a scenario where I want to append a prefix `'*'` to a tab in a `QTabWidget` in case it is not saved.

The relevant code is working fine and something along these lines:

```cpp
    auto index = m_tabWidget->indexOf(tab);
    auto tabName = (canBeSaved) ? "*" + tab->getName()
                                : tab->getName();

    if (m_tabWidget->tabText(index) != tabName)
        m_tabWidget->setTabText(index, tabName);
```

The alternative is to always call the setter without condition

```cpp
m_tabWidget->setTabText(index, tabName);
```

**My Question is:**

> Does checking the `tabName` for changes make up the expense of the (potentially) skipped `setText`?
>
> Is there a general rule of thumb, whether to check for equality before setting a variable or not?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter in these cases. Pick what looks clearest to you and your team. Don't sweat over it.

There's no general rule of thumb either. There are specific cases where checking before setting is a must because of some side effects in the setter and there are specific cases where settings regardless is a must because of performance criticality / checking is expensive / multithreading, this case is neither.

Comment: Thanks. In general, is setting and getting equally fast? It would make sense for Qt to make that check by itself to reduce updating the UI, right?

Comment: @gitnoob Yes you can assume so. Setting and getting is too specific so its not like that for every getter/setter, it's a per-situation assessment.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you don't know what a function does, be careful about calling it without checking if it's needed. A setter may just simply update a member variable, or it may call a bunch of other functions to recalculate its layout, for example. In this case, you have access to Qt's source code, so you could check to see how trivial of a call it is.

I also would add that in Qt you may want to be careful of emitting unnecessary signals. It's very common for setters in Qt to emit signals when a value has changed. For example, let's say my setter looks like this:

```
void MyObject::setSomething(int val) {
    m_val = val;
    emit valChanged();
}
```

If I call that without checking if the value has actually changed, I could be broadcasting to the rest of the application that something has changed even when it has not. It may still be harmless, or it may not, depending on who is listening for that signal.

It's a good general practice for setters to do their own checking, like this:

```
void MyObject::setSomething(int val) {
    if (m_val != val) {
        m_val = val;
        emit valChanged();
    }
}
```

That way, the caller does not need to worry about doing the checking.